# Unable to ReDim array from C# class in VB6

Tags: c#, arrays, com, vb6, marshalling

I have to use C# class in vb6 which contains arrays.
I'm marshalling them as Safe Arrays but I can't redim them in VB6, although in watch I can see that they have correct types.
When I was using the same marshaling in struct it was working fine. The difference between them is that in struct I had fields and in class I have properties, so I think that I have some problem with that, but I can't find it.

Here is my test class:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("179181EF-8689-4CCA-B43E-34145F5A9608")]
public interface IBook
{
    string Title { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] get; [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] set; }
    string[] Keywords { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)] get; [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)] set; }
    int[] Years { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)] get; [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)] set; }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("61AF9F28-3588-4C26-A971-2C42CFC2040B")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Book : IBook
{
    public string[] Keywords { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int[] Years { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my vb6 code:

```
Dim book As New TestProject.book

Set book = New TestProject.book

ReDim book.years(1 To 3)
```

When I try to compile it, I'm receiving compile error: "Method or data member not found"

Comment: shouldn't it be `book.Years` with a capital Y in the first place?

Comment: In vb6 it doesn't matter.

Comment: Parentheses mean too many things in VB.  There is a syntax ambiguity because VB also allows properties to have an argument.  Not supported in C# but VB6 doesn't know that.  Consider going slower with Dim years() As Integer: years = book.years: Redim Preserve years(1 to 3).  Surely you need Preserve btw.  Maybe Redim book.years()(1 to 3) works, I can't test this anymore.

Comment: I've tried that, but it's compile error. I don't need preserve for initial initialization, but this doesn't matter, it's not working with or without it.

Answer (score 1):

I duplicate code in c# to find issue.  It looks like in c# you have to use a temporary variable (temp)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test test = new Test();

            Test.Book book1 = new Test.Book  { Keywords = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }, Title = "123", Years = new int[] { 30 } };
            Test.IBook Ibook1 = (Test.IBook)book1;
            Test.Book book2 = (Test.Book)Ibook1;

            int[] temp = Ibook1.Years;
            Array.Resize(ref temp, 3);
            Ibook1.Years = temp;

        }

    }
    public class Test
    {


        [ComVisible(true)]
        [Guid("179181EF-8689-4CCA-B43E-34145F5A9608")]
        public interface IBook
        {

            string Title { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] get; [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] set; }
            string[] Keywords { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)] get; [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)] set; }
            int[] Years { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)] get; [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)] set; }
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        [Guid("61AF9F28-3588-4C26-A971-2C42CFC2040B")]
        [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
        public class Book : IBook
        {
            public string[] Keywords { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public int[] Years { get; set; }
        }
    }


}
```